# 301 Redirect using just routes, no controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, http-status-code-301

I'd like to do a 301 redirect, but I want a catch all.  What I currently have is, the domain is hosted on Wordpress and I have both pages and posts. If those pages or posts don't exist on my new rails app, I want to redirect to the home page.

I'm using Heroku to host this, so I can't do it with the web server, as far as I know, so I need to do it inside of Rails. I don't have a controller per se, but I could highjack the page's controller and use that. Is there a way I can put something at the bottom of the routes file that says, "If this page doesn't exist, re-route it to the homepage"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As from [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html), 3.10 you could use advanced constraints and redirects like:

```
matches '*any_path' => redirect('/')
```

Be sure to add this global route after your pages routes as this route match all paths.

Comment: But does this provide the 301 redirect or what type of redirect is it? I can't find that in the docs you link to.

Comment: According to http://www.camelpunch.com/web-development/tutorials/301-redirect-with-rails/ this does in fact create the 301.

Answer (score 1):

Mark's answer didn't seem to work for me, but it pointed me in the right direct, so I've given him the green check mark.

What I ended having to do is add the following to my routes.rb:

`match "*rest", :to => "pages#redirect"`

and then in my pages controller do the following:

```
def redirect
  redirect_to root_path
end
```